# How to start Sidekiq in RubyMine?

Tags: rubymine, sidekiq

I'm using RubyMine 6.3.  I tried to configure Sidekiq in RubyMine but I can't start it.

How would I configure and start Sidekiq in RubyMine?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

1. Go to Run/Debug Configurations
2. Add a new Gem Command
3. Enter 'sidekiq' as the Gem name and Executable name
4. Check 'Run the script in the contexst of bundle (bundle exec) under the 'Bundler' tab
5. Click 'Apply' and then run it.

[image]

Comment: Does using this method automatically reload sidekiq when code is changed or do we need to use something like rerun?

Comment: @Altonymous no it does not, you would have to use another method to reload sidekiq. I'm pretty sure you could modify this to incorporate rerun with it.

Comment: is there anyway to launch sidekiq before rails starts? You can add it as a `before launch` task but it will wait until the process completes, which is what I do not want because i want them to run concurrently.

Comment: This is also the way debug sidekiq jobs in RubyMine